# TrayIcon doesn't show notification

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, trayicon

I use this code to show a `TrayIcon` it works and the `TrayIcon` appears in the Systray but it doesn't show the `BalloonHint`; I tried to change some setting but it still doesn't show the notification

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayIcon1.Hint := 'Hint';
  TrayIcon1.AnimateInterval := 200;
  TrayIcon1.BalloonTitle := 'Hint';
  TrayIcon1.BalloonHint := 'Double click to restore Application';
  TrayIcon1.BalloonFlags := bfInfo;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Minimize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Hide();
  WindowState := wsMinimized;
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  TrayIcon1.Animate := True;
  TrayIcon1.ShowBalloonHint;
end;

procedure TMainForm.TrayIcon1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayIcon1.Visible := False;
  Show();
  WindowState := wsNormal;
  Application.BringToFront();
end;
```

what is wrong with this code?

---

The project is originally written in Delphi7 and now upgraded to DelphiXE8.

Comment: Why are you changing `WindowState`? It's enough to hide the main form

Comment: I just used it to make sure `MainForm` Is minimized

Comment: You've hidden the main form. That's what removes the button from the taskbar. Minimizing a hidden form is pointless. Doing so means that you forget whether the form was normalised or maximised or minimized.

Comment: I thought minimize what removes it from taskbar so I wanted to confirm it, now it's clear, I will delete this line, thank you

Comment: When you minimize a window by clicking on the minimize button, the taskbar button remains. Taskbar buttons are shown for **visible** top-level un-owned windows. So, when you hide such a window, its taskbar button is removed.

Comment: Now I understand how it works, I have misunderstood it, thank you for detailed explanation.

Comment: Which OS is on the machine where you can't get this to work?

Comment: @MartynA it's Windows 10 Pro x64 and all other apps show notifications normally only this app doesn't show notification

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no problem with the code, it looks windows problem
**Reinstall windows fixed it**

Comment: The question is old so I just didn't want to leave it without answer forever, I didn't delete it because maybe someone else have the same problem and keep searching and changing codes just like I did before I reinstall windows

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the code.
It appears to be your OS level settings of `Notification Area Icons` that is wrong (= `Hide icon and notifications`).
Open `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons` and select either `Only show notifications` or `Show icon and notifications` for your application.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Obviously it works on mine, it was the first thing I checked.

Comment: `Notifications` is already set to `Show icon and notifications` for this apps and all other apps and all other apps show notifications without problem.

Comment: @DelphiLover did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes I did try it, It still doesn't show Notification.

Comment: @DelphiLover You have set `Animate` to true and `AnimateInterval` to 200. This doesn't affect the function for me, but if you try with false? Do you actually have `Icons` set? Or any other properties in `Object Inspector`? `BalloonTimeout`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I did try it now with `Animate' to False it still same.

Comment: @DelphiLover Thanks, then, if you put a button on the form, add `OnClick` event and write `TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  TrayIcon1.ShowBalloonHint;`? Do you have more than one `ApplicationEvents` in your app?

Comment: I did try it still same, I have only one `ApplicationEvents` used for `TrayIcon`; I usually use this code and it works only with this app it doesn't the only different I wrote this app with `Delphi7` but now I use `Delphi XE8` should this cause a problem?

Comment: @DelphiLover But do you have other Applicationevents in your app, even if for other purposes. They are activated in sequence and can prevent events to be passed further on. You have indicated Delphi-XE in the tags, so with wich version is this app made with? Is it 'upgraded' from Delphi 7 to XE8?

Comment: I have no other `ApplicationEvents` only Minimize event for tray icon; Yes it's `Upgraded` from `Delphi7` to `Delphi XE8`

Comment: @DelphiLover I edited your question accordingly. I have a feeling this may be the key, but need time to investigate. I'll be back! err... maybe

Comment: @DelphiLover AFAIK, Delphi 7 did not have a TTrayIcon component. Have you used a 3rd party component in D7 and if so, are you still using that, or have you added the TTrayIcon now in XE8? If you are using an old component, remove it and add the one from XE8. If this doesn't help, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I didn't use 3rd party component I just added `TTrayIcon` in `Delphi XE8`, Thank you for your trying to help me, you did what you can. I will keep trying maybe find out what cause this problem

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of current and future Internet searchers, i'll say that my problem was with XE5 and Windows 10 (it worked fine in Windows XP). Turned out that I stupidly turned on the priority mode, which hides Notifications .. and also trayicon's balloonhints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it a bit differently.  First of all  you need to check for when the form minimizes. That could be done by catching the message `WM_SIZE`

```
procedure WMSize(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SIZE;
```

And then:

```
procedure TForm1.WMSize(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.WParam  = SIZE_MINIMIZED then ....
end;
```

Typically you also want the close button to minimize the Application. That could be achived by implementing a CloseQuery event.

I've made you a small example based on your own code.

First the DFM code:

```
object Form11: TForm11
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form11'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCloseQuery = FormCloseQuery
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnHide = FormHide
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object TrayIcon1: TTrayIcon
    OnDblClick = TrayIcon1DblClick
    Left = 312
    Top = 152
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Left = 184
    Top = 112
    object Close1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Close'
      Default = True
      OnClick = Close1Click
    end
  end
end
```

Then the actual sourcecode:

```
unit Unit11;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm11 = class(TForm)
    TrayIcon1: TTrayIcon;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    Close1: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormHide(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure Close1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TrayIcon1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    AllowClose: Boolean;
  public
    procedure WMSize(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SIZE;
  end;

var
  Form11: TForm11;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm11.Close1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AllowClose := True;
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm11.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := AllowClose;
  if not AllowClose then
    Hide;
end;

procedure TForm11.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AllowClose := false;
  TrayIcon1.Hint := 'Hint';
  TrayIcon1.AnimateInterval := 200;
  TrayIcon1.BalloonTitle := 'Hint';
  TrayIcon1.BalloonHint := 'Double click to restore Application';
  TrayIcon1.BalloonFlags := bfInfo;
end;

procedure TForm11.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  TrayIcon1.Animate := True;
  TrayIcon1.ShowBalloonHint;
end;

procedure TForm11.TrayIcon1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayIcon1.Visible := false;
  Show();
  WindowState := wsNormal;
  Application.BringToFront();
end;

procedure TForm11.WMSize(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.WParam = SIZE_MINIMIZED then
    Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I just tried it now, it still doesn't show `Notification`

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. I've just made a "new" test from the code i've posted.  And it works very well. Download my code here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x03g8i01yew9ehe/Hint.zip?dl=0

Comment: I usually use the code in my question and it works always only with this app it doesn't work so I want to find out where is the problem, if I make new project it will work without problems.

Comment: The problem is you are using Application.OnMinimize and not listening for Message WM_SIZE. I've allready told you.

Comment: Yes that was my code, but I did try your code with Message `WM_SIZE` and it doesn't work too

Comment: @DelphiLover if you use the code I provided then it works.

Comment: I know your code should work but I used it and it doesn't work, Also my code should work but it doesn't; that's the problem.

Comment: @DelphiLover my code WORKS. If it doesn't work at your computer then you are doing something wrong

Comment: @JensBorrisholt:  Don't you mean that it works where you've tested it?